# DynamoDBMapper load vs query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The DynamoDBMapper provides different ways to read one item from a table:

- query
- load

Is there a recommendation, which of them to use? In a quick test, the following two code snippets return the same "MyEntry" item for a table with primary key=hash and range key=date, whereas the query method is roughly 10% faster.

**load**

```java
public MyEntry getEntryForDay(final Integer hash, final LocalDate date) {
    return mapper.load(MyEntry.class, hash, date);
}
```

**query**

```java
public MyEntry getEntryForDay(final Integer hash, final LocalDate date) {
    final MyEntry hashKeyValues = new MyEntry ();
    hashKeyValues.setHash(hash);
    final Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()//
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())//
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(new LocalDateMarshaller().marshall(date)));
    final DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntry> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntry>()//
            .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyValues)//
            .withRangeKeyCondition("date", rangeKeyCondition)//
            .withLimit(1);
    final List<MyEntry> storedEntries = mapper
            .query(MyEntry.class, queryExpression);
    if (storedEntries.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return storedEntries.get(0);
}
```

Comment: *"Roughly 10% faster"*. How did you benchmark these? What are your measurements?

Comment: I didn't properly benchmark, just done a time measurement. Insert with mapper.load took 90ms with a sample table, the same insert with mapper.query took 110ms with the same table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, now as I'm getting more used to work with DynamoDB it turns out that a bug in the mapper.query code is causing the poorer performance:

- The "withLimit(1)" does not in fact limit the total results returned in the list but instead the results are returned in a "PaginatedQueryList" and the actual items are lazily loaded from DB if accessed. WithLimit(1) actually limits the items loaded with each request.
- The actual bug is the part "if (storedEntries.size() == 0)", as the size() call loads in fact ALL items in the list. With the withLimit(1) this results in the poorest possible performance.

The correct code for the mapper query is:

```java
public MyEntry getEntryForDay(final Integer hash, final LocalDate date) {
    final MyEntry hashKeyValues = new MyEntry ();
    hashKeyValues.setHash(hash);
    final Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition()//
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ.toString())//
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(new LocalDateMarshaller().marshall(date)));
    final DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntry> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyEntry>()//
            .withHashKeyValues(hashKeyValues)//
            .withRangeKeyCondition("date", rangeKeyCondition)//
            .withLimit(1);
    final List<MyEntry> storedEntries = mapper
            .query(MyEntry.class, queryExpression);
    if (storedEntries.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return storedEntries.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Load and Query are different operations:

If you have a hash key only schema, they perform the same operation - retrieve the item with the hash key specified.

If you have a hash-range schema, load retrieves a specific item identified by a single hash + range pair. Query retrieves all items that have the specified hash key and meet the range key conditions.

Since you are using the equality operator for both the hash key and range key, the operations are exactly equivalent.