# DynamoDBMappingException: no RANGE key value present

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to `NoSQL` and `Amazon Dynamo DB`. I am trying to retreive a user by `username` first from a `DynamoDB` `UserMaster` table.

I have a table `UserMaster` with 5 attributes(`username`, `correct-hash`, `email`, `lastLogin`, `role`), each of type `String` and I have a corresponding `UsermasterBean` mapped to the table `UserMaster`. `UserMaster` table's Partition Key(Hashkey) is  `username` and `Sort key(Range Key)` is `correct-hash`

**UsermasterBean**

```
    @DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UserMaster")
    public class UsermasterBean {
    
    private String username;
    private String correctHash;
    private String email;
    private String lastLogin;
    private String role;
    
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "username")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "correct-hash")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "correct-hash")
    public String getCorrectHash() {
        return correctHash;
    }
    
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "last-login")
    public String getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }
    
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "role")
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    ....
    ....
   }
```

**Retrieve data from UI:**

```
UsermasterBean usermasterBean = new UsermasterBean();
UsermasterDao usermasterDao = new UsermasterDao();

usermasterBean.setUsername(username.getValue()); // Get the username from UI form
final String inputtedPassword = password.getValue(); // Get the password from UI form

UsermasterBean retrievedUserBean = usermasterDao.findByUsernameAndPassword(usermasterBean,inputtedPassword);
```

**Validate User:**

```
public UsermasterBean findByUsernameAndPassword(final UsermasterBean usermasterBean, final String inputtedPassword)
            throws IOException {
        AmazonDynamoDBClientHandler amazonDynamoDBClientHandler = AmazonDynamoDBClientHandler.getNewInstance();
        UsermasterBean retrievedUser;
        try {
            AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = amazonDynamoDBClientHandler.createNewClient();
            DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
            retrievedUser = dynamoDBMapper.load(usermasterBean.getClass(), usermasterBean.getUsername());
            System.out.println("RETRIEVED CORRECT-HASH FROM DATABASE: " + retrievedUser.getCorrectHash()); // Check if hash retrieved is correct for this user.

            // PasswordUtilityManager.verifyPassword(inputtedPassword,retrievedUser.getCorrectHash());
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw ioException;
        } finally {
            amazonDynamoDBClientHandler.shutdownClient();
        }
        return retrievedUser;
}
```

**Problem:**

`retrievedUser = dynamoDBMapper.load(usermasterBean.getClass(), usermasterBean.getUsername());` throws `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException`

I am expecting `retrievedUser.getCorrectHash()` should display the hashed password stored in database as a `String` so that I can verify if the inputted password creates the same hash as retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is being throw because the DynamoDBMapper is expecting the range key to be passed in too (as your DynamoDB table contains a range key of `correct-hash`).

The correct function call should be as below

```
retrievedUser = dynamoDBMapper.load(usermasterBean.getClass(), usermasterBean.getUsername(), usermasterBean.getCorrectHash());
```

As this is presumably the hash for your users password, you can specify a hashed copy of the password provided by the user. If this returns no results in DynamoDB you can assume that either their username or password is incorrect.

Comment: Chris, as per your advice, `retrievedUser = dynamoDBMapper.load(usermasterBean.getClass(), usermasterBean.getUsername(),usermasterBean.getCorrectHash());` - throws the same exception because I still do not have the `correct-hash` to pass it to the load method unless I fetch it from database. That's why, I want to retrieve `correct-hash` by `username` & check if inputted password creates the same `correct-hash` as retrieved by database. It works fine  when I hard coded the `correct-hash` to test it. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: If you're able to hash `inputtedPassword` and pass that in then if it returns no result you know that the credentials did not match. Alternatively you would need to create a new DynamoDB table and not have a sort column

Answer (score 2):

As per your data model, there can be more than one entry in the `UserMaster` table for a single user (`username`) which is not your intention. (Why would a user have two hashed passwords?)

Do not model `correctHash` as a range key. If you do, DynamoDB mandates you to provide both the hash and range key when calling `load` (else you have to `query`).

See: [DynamoDBMapper load vs query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850030/dynamodbmapper-load-vs-query)